# Git submodule update process needs password while trying to connect the Azure DevOps to siteground server

Tags: wordpress, git, azure, ssh, git-submodules

I have a WordPress website repo with two **submodules**, one for connecting to the theme, and one for pulling a special plugin.
Currently both the submodules are hosted on **Azure DevOps** in the form of **singular repositories**. I could easily clone the whole submodules, initiate, and **update** them into my **local** machine, however, when I try to do the same scenario on my **siteground** host, it asks a **password** for updating the submodule;

**It has read the folder while keeping them empty.

- I have tried to create a public ssh, import that on both Azure DevOps
  and Siteground SSH tools
- I have used PAT (Personal Access Token) on
  Azure DevOps

But the password is asked again and again

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
git@ssh.dev.azure.com's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I would be really grateful if you could help me solve what exactly is this password!

Comment: A submodule is a *separate repository*. You will need access to that repository. To find the repository's URL, look in the `.gitmodules` file in the superproject.

Comment: thanks @torek. Actually I am using SSH credentials for accessing the two repositories hosted on the Azure DevOps

Answer (score 1):

First, check that your key is actually working (meaning its public key has been registered)

```
ssh -Tv git@ssh.dev.azure.com
```

If it does, double-check the URL registered in the `.gitmodules` is actually an SSH one.
The PAT is only used for HTTPS URLs.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. Where should I check the registered public key? Siteground does not give me a root access but the access before www/tmp files which I can have access trough putty.
Moreover, there is an SSH Tools section inside of my hosting panel where I could add or import public/private key.

Comment: I could fixed the issue using SSH url and PAT. Thanks. But the server still wants a passphrase while trying to init or update the git submodule when I use SSH rule

Comment: @ShayanFaghihi Can you test with a dedicated SSH key without created without passphrase?

Comment: The point is that -based on my experience- Azure DevOps does not let you assign passphrase for your SSH key. I wish I could

Comment: @ShayanFaghihi OK. So if  Azure DevOps does not let you assign passphrase, does that mean it would work with a passphrass-less key?

Comment: I have tried the similar flow on my local machine using DevOps public SSH key, and not passphrase was needed, however, when I work on the online server, it keeps asking me for passphrase. The good point that you have mentioned earlier, by changing the contact method to HTTPS, and of course using PAT, everything works fine and great. Really appreciate that

Comment: @ShayanFaghihi Probably because locally your passphrase is cached by an ssh agent. Try with creating a new key without passphrase.